# stack of actions for one sparite in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, stack, action

I've got a question: My games hero can jump (**CCJumpTo**) and move to forward and backward direction (**CCMoveTo**).

I faced with problem: if game recived a command from user to move the hero, but in this time hero is jumping (**CCJumpTo**), how can I do this command after the end of jumping. (can I use some stack of actions for one sparite in cocos2d)

I can't use immediately **[self.sprite stopAllActions];** to begin **CCMoveTo** because the hero have to finish the jump action and if I use **CCMoveTo** the action **CCJumpTo** will not finish. Hero can't jump and start to move to forward and backward  at height.

sorry for my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you can store your stack of actions in array, then run action like this

```
- (void) runNextAction
{
    id actionFromStack = [stack objectAtIndex: 0];
    [stack removeObjectAtIndex: 0];
    id callback = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget: self selector: @selector(runNextAction)];
    id sequence = [CCSequence actionOne: actionFromStack two: callback];
    [self runAction: sequence];
}
```

Comment: thanks, I understand, Is the cocos2d has own option to do this?

Comment: if such mechanism exists, i don't know anything about it =)