# Actions queue cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Can I do something like actions queue? For example, I have rotate action on click, but if user  clicked 10 times, it's must do all rotations step by step (Now it's cancel last rotation action and starting do new by list clicking)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615729/stack-of-actions-for-one-sparite-in-cocos2d/10616447#10616447

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i'm concerned there is no functionality in the SDK for that. But you can write a method which is when ever called pushing the action in an array. When done the finished-notification of the animation should return with an delegate a success state. Then you can pop the action from the array and look up if there was pushed another action meanwhile and start over again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Offcourse, what you are looking for is called `CCSequence`. Here is an example below:

```
id moveAction = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:2 position:ccp(size.width/2,0)];
id rotateAction = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration: 1 angle:90.0f];

[mySprite runAction: [CCSequence actions:moveAction, rotateAction, moveAction, rotateAction, nil]];
```

Comment: yes. But I need add actions to queue, not call two actions, I can't know when action will be called (It's must called after finishing first and all will be ok)

Comment: Yes, try using `mySprite.actions`. Eg: `[mySprite runAction:[CCSequence actions: mySprite.actions, newAction, nil]];`.

Comment: Is there any class with an actions property?